# Hierarchical data by using Winforms (.Net)

Tags: winforms, hierarchical

I have 3 dropdown list with the below data format.

```
 Dropdown-1    Dropdown-2      Dropdown-3
-----------    --------------      ---------------
Parent-1          Boy-1                 Girl-1
Parent-2          Boy-2                 Girl-2
Parent-3          Boy-3                 Girl-3
```

Based on the selection from the dropdown boxes;

If I select 
          Parent-2 from Dropdown-1
          Boy-1 from Dropdown-2
          Girl-2 from Dropdown-3

Then I need result in the following hierarchical format:

```
 Parent 1
  Boy 1
       Name 1:
       Age 1: 
  Girl 1
       Name 1:
       Age 1: 
  Girl 2
       Name 2:
       Age 2: 
 Parent 2
   Boy 1
          Name 1:
          Age 1: 
   Girl 1
          Name 1:
          Age 1: 
   Girl 2
          Name 2:
           Age 2:
```

Need your support on this.

Thanks in advance,

kka_anand

Answer (score 0):

I tried with TreeView class and able to create Parent and child object. When I tried to create grantchild. It throws error in the below marked area. Any suggestion to fix it.

//=============================================================

```
              // Add a child treenode for each NameAge object in the current Gender object.
                foreach (NameAge noOfNameAge in noOfParents.ParentOrder)
                {
                    controllerOutput.Nodes[parentArray.IndexOf(noOfParents)].Nodes[genderArray.IndexOf(noOfGender)].Nodes.Add(
                        new TreeNode(noOfNameAge.NameAgeID));
                }
```

//=============================================================

```
    // Start of parent class.
    public class Parent : System.Object
    {
        private string parentName = "";
        protected ArrayList parentOrder = new ArrayList();

        public Floor(string parentName)
        {
            this.floorName = parentName;
        }

        public string ParentName
        {
            get { return this.parentName; }
            set { this.parentName = value; }
        }

        public ArrayList ParentOrder
        {
            get { return this.parentOrder; }
        }

    } // End of parent class.



    // Start of gender (Boy/Girl) class.
    public class Corridor : System.Object
    {
        private string genderID = "";
        protected ArrayList genderOrder = new ArrayList();

        public Gender(string genderid)
        {
            this.genderID = genderid;
        }

        public string GenderID
        {
            get { return this.genderID; }
            set { this.genderID = value; }
        }

        public ArrayList GenderOrder
        {
            get { return this.genderOrder; }
        }

    } // End of gender class.



    // Start of NameAge class.
    public class NameAge : System.Object
    {
        private string nameageID = "";
        protected ArrayList nameageOrder = new ArrayList();

        public NameAge(string nameageid)
        {
            this.nameageID = nameageid;
        }

        public string NameAgeID
        {
            get { return this.NameAgeID; }
            set { this.NameAgeID = value; }
        }

        public ArrayList NameAgeOrder
        {
            get { return this.nameageOrder; }
        }

    } // End of NameAge class.



    private ArrayList parentArray = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList genderArray = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList nameageArray = new ArrayList();

    private void FillControllerTreeView()
    {

        // Add parent to the ArrayList of Parent objects.
        for (int x = 1; x <= Convert.ToInt32(DropDown-1.SelectedItem.ToString()); x++)
        {
            parentArray.Add(new Parent("Parent - " + x.ToString()));
        }


        // Add Gender(Boy/Girl) to each Parent object in the ArrayList.
        foreach (Parent parent in parentArray)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y <= Convert.ToInt32(DropDown-2.SelectedItem.ToString()); y++)
            {
                parent.ParentOrder.Add(new Gender("Boy - " + y.ToString()));  
            }

            for (int z = 1; z <= Convert.ToInt32(DropDown-3.SelectedItem.ToString()); z++)
            {
                parent.ParentOrder.Add(new Gender("Girl - " + z.ToString()));
            }
        }


        foreach (NameAge nameage in nameageArray)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= 2; y++)
            {
                nameage.NameAgeOrder.Add(new NameAge("Light - " + y.ToString()));
            }

            nameage.NameAgeOrder.Add(new NameAge("AC - "));

        }


        controllerOutput.BeginUpdate();
        controllerOutput.Nodes.Clear();

        foreach (Parent noOfParents in parentArray)
        {
            controllerOutput.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(noOfParents.ParentName));

            // Add a child treenode for each gender object in the current Parent object.
            foreach (Gender noOfGender in noOfParents.ParentOrder)
            {
                controllerOutput.Nodes[parentArray.IndexOf(noOfParents)].Nodes.Add(
                          new TreeNode(noOfGender.GenderID));


                // Add a child treenode for each NameAge object in the current Gender object.
                foreach (NameAge noOfNameAge in noOfParents.ParentOrder)
                {
                    controllerOutput.Nodes[parentArray.IndexOf(noOfParents)].Nodes[genderArray.IndexOf(noOfGender)].Nodes.Add(
                        new TreeNode(noOfNameAge.NameAgeID));
                }

            }
        }

        controllerOutput.EndUpdate();
    }
```

Thanks